# How to define a command that defines macro with default value

Tags: macros, csname

I have to define a lot of text variables with some default value.

I do it next way:

```
\def\name#1{\gdef\@name{#1}}%
\name{Alex}
```

I tried to automatize this process, but it is not working

```
\newcommand{\DefineAndSet}[2]{%
    \def\csname #1\endcsname ##1{\gdef\@\csname #1\endcsname{##1}}%
    \csname #1\endcsname{#2}
}
```

My MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\DefineAndSet}[2]{%
    \def\csname #1\endcsname ##1{\gdef\@\csname #1\endcsname{##1}}%
    \csname #1\endcsname{#2}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \DefineAndSet{name}{Alex}
    
    \name
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first line in the definition of `\DefineAndSet` needs to be something like `\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname ##1{\expandafter\gdef\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}}%`, since TeX needs to construct the macro name *before* it does the `\def`/`\gdef`. (You probably also want a `%` after `\csname #1\endcsname{#2}`.)

Comment: You need the `\expandafter`, as noted in the above comment.  Without it, you are trying and failing to redefine the `\csname` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code: you need to build the symbolic token with `\csname` before `\def` or `\gdef` see it. And the `@` should go inside `\csname`.

```
\newcommand{\DefineAndSet}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname ##1{\expandafter\gdef\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}}%
    \csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

On the other hand, I don't see the need for the `\@name` command.

```
\newcommand{\DefineAndSet}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
  #2%
}
```

would do what you need. With a problem, though: you're not checking whether `\name` (or whatever is produced from the first argument to `\DefineAndSet`) is already defined. This can be overcome by

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefineAndSet}[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{\gdef#1{#2}}#2%
}
\makeatother
```

to be simply called by

```
\DefineAndSet{\name}{Alex}
```